# Hidden Field Persistence

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

I am writing a web app with CodeIgniter and jQuery

I have multiple drop downs that are dependent on each others. I solved this using AJAX with JSON,  but once again I faced some troubles.

When I submit, if the form doesn't respect the requirements (ex. missing a mandatory field) I lose the data from the dropdowns.

What I did next was create hidden field to store the IDs of the dropdown selections and rebuild it after the post but still didn't make it because the values of the hidden fields don't persist across posts....

What should I do?

Comment: Do JavaScript validation so you don't post unless necessary. Of course, you still should validate server side, so this doesn't really answer your question...

Comment: Showing some code would be great. Are you using the built-in CI form helper? Also, like Justin said, do the JS validation before submitting.

Comment: JAvascript validation is an excelent help but now I need to find a way to use the Translate function on the javascript messages :(

Answer (score 0):

I'd say do an ajax call to validate with codeigniter before submitting. Seems unnecessary to send a request, then submit - but think of how much better your user experience would be without the page refresh just to show them an error.